# Angular: ng-reflect attributes not showing in published application

Tags: asp.net, .net, angular

I have an angular 9 application with an ASP.NET Web API backend.

When I run the app from visual studio, I can see ng-reflect-... attributes that angular usually adds to the DOM in development mode.

However, when I publish the application using

```
dotnet publish --configuration Debug --output ../_Debug
```

and I run the application locally, I cannot see the ng-reflect-... attributes.

Note that the angular application is in development mode. It prints the following to the console:

```
Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
```

How can I get those attributes to show in the published application?

Answer (score -1):

Set the "optimization" parameter of "ng build" to "false".

https://angular.io/cli/build

Comment: in the link provided I haven't found anything related to ng-reflect-disabled